# translate string into positions of list of tokens

Tags: python

I have a list of bout 5000 unique words/tokens, each word (a smiley counts as a word) is per line. Im trying to produce something that will work for SVM for python.

Imagine example list only has a few words

```
happy
sad
is
:(
i
the
day
am
today
:)
```

and my strings are:

```
tweets =['i am happy today :)','is today the sad day :(']
```

Then output per tweet is:

```
5:1 8:1 1:1 9:1 10:1
3:1 9:1 6:1 2:1 4:1
```

Notice this format : , this means the first digit before the colon, should be referencing the word using its line number/position in list . e.g. ':)' is the tenth word in the list (text file, 1 token per line).

I was thinking bout creating a function that reads a text file, and places each line (each word/token) into 1 place into a list or dictionary, so that i can read a word from each tweet and translate it into a digit based on its position in the list.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this in python?
then I was thinking something like this:

```
 for i in tweets:
         <translate-words-into-list-position>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
words = ['happy', 'sad', 'is', ':(', 'i', 'the', 'day', 'am', 'today', ':)']
d = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(words, start=1)}
tweets =['i am happy today :)','is today the sad day :(']
for tweet in tweets:
    print ' '.join(['{0}:1'.format(d[w]) for w in tweet.split() if w in d])


5:1 8:1 1:1 9:1 10:1
3:1 9:1 6:1 2:1 7:1 4:1
```

If words is a `file` you can still use it with this solution, just remember to `.rstrip('\n')` the line. eg.

```
with open('words.txt', 'rU') as f:
    d = {w.rstrip('\n'): i for i, w in enumerate(f, start=1)}
```

Comment: so if words is a text file (1 word per line), it should be something like `words = open("wordlist.txt")` and then use the `.rstrip('\n')` in which way?

Comment: @RHK-S8 that's okay but it's better to use a `with` block which calls `.close()` on the file automatically, I've updated code

Comment: i have replaced `words` with `f`, was giving an error. It now works, but im getting a next error `  File "test.py", line 7, in main
    print ' '.join(['{0}:1'.format(d[w]) for w in tweet.split()])
KeyError: 'i'`

Comment: @RHK-S8 the word `i` doesn't exist in the dictionary? What would you like to do in that case? You may choose to save all your words as case insenstivie eg. `d = {w.lower().rstrip('\n'): i for i, w in enumerate(f, start=1)}` and then check `d[c.lower()]` and you may also provide a default argument if a key index doesn't exist, eg. `d.get(c, 'NOT FOUND')`

Comment: if a word is not in the list, it should just skip it and move on to next word. Not all words contained in the tweets, will be there. The wordlist is going to change a lot, due to testing to see which words work best in my analysis stage

Comment: @RKK-S8 added predicate to the list comprehension now (`if w in d`)

Comment: this seems to solve the error part, but it now shows 2 empty lines eventhough `i` and 'happy' is in the list.

Comment: i printed the list (d), and it seems to have `\r` behind each word? dyu think this has to with not matching the word?

Comment: list was made in windows, hence the problem...but i fixed it :)

Comment: @RHK-S8 congratulations, added `rU` mode for other viewers

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> D = dict(zip(words, count(1)))
>>> tweets =['i am happy today :)','is today the sad day :(']
>>> [["{}:1".format(D[k]) for k in t.split() if k in D] for t in tweets]
[['5:1', '8:1', '1:1', '9:1', '10:1'], ['3:1', '9:1', '6:1', '2:1', '7:1', '4:1']]
```